# How do I change the text color and icon color in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

So, I have seen answers all over for how to change the "cancel" and navigation button items, however it's (as far as I can tell) not the answer I'm looking for.

On Ipad (inside a popover, there are no buttons other than the icons + their labels), I can change the background color of UIActivityViewController from the default gray to black. However, now the text and the simple icons are now invisible since they are their default black (example the copy icon. or the print icon). I would like to shift these white.

It does not need to apply to any other view/screen/etc other than the UIActivityViewController.

How can I achieve this? Every answer I find refers to other parts of the UI like what happens on launch or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge I don't think you can change the text and the icon color of the default items. The activity controller class doesn't provide such property. If you want you can create your own custom icon and text as activity item and use them based on your need. There are plenty of resources about that. like I said changing the color and the icons of the default items can't seem feasible to me... Hope helps.